# TypeScript function overloading. IDE argument type confusion

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ide, webstorm, typescript-typings

I'm trying to achieve good developer experience for my TypeScript API, but I'm facing unexpected issue.
When overloading function like shown below:

```js
/** Comment 1 */
function a(key: 'key1', args: { arg1: number }): string
/** Comment 2 */
function a(key: 'key2', args: { arg2: number }): string
function a(key: string, args) { }
```

When someone is trying to call that function in an IDE *(I tried VSCode and WebStorm)*

```js
a('key2', { })
//         ^
```

the IDE suggests object property based on union of second type. *(in this case `arg1` and `arg2`)*

I would like It to behave similar to this code:

```js
/** Comment 1 */
function a(key: 'key1'): (args: { arg1: number }) => string
/** Comment 2 */
function a(key: 'key2'): (args: { arg2: number }) => string
function a(key: string, args) { }
```

where when calling

```js
a('key2')({ })
//         ^
```

only needed properties show up.

Is it possible to get the same behavior in the first case?

Comment: Is there a reason why `key` is typed as `string` and not `"key1" | "key2"`?

Comment: no, it may be union, just laziness, i don't want to repeat the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem - for instance in event listener contexts - and I faced it myself recently. Fortunately, there is a simple and elegant solution.

First of all, in your question there are two slightly different formulations of the problem; once, the object you want to type correctly is another argument to `a`, and once it is the singular argument to a function that you want to return from `a`. The following solution should work for both versions, but I'll present it for the first scenario, which should be more common.

The main trick is to *avoid* overloads and replace them by a single generic; that also makes handling `a` and typing much easier. As far as I can think, this should always be possible in the cases you describe.

**Step 1**: **Define your function signatures/overloads by an interface**:

```
interface Signatures {
    key1: {arg1: number};
    key2: {arg2: number};
}
```

Of course, that would be a bit more difficult for more than 2 arguments; but scenarios that are typical for the mentioned problem to arise usually have exactly 2 arguments - one key and one value.

**Step 2**: **Define a single function generic function signature**:

```
function a<K extends keyof Signatures>(key: K, args: Signatures[K]): string {
    return 'hello world'; // TODO
}
```

Then, when you call `a('key1',` ), `args` is automatically inferred to be of type `{arg1: number}`.

Comment: Thanks, that is almost what I need, the only problem with this and the reason why I went for function overload in the first place is that I would like to include some additional information in function documentation depending on first argument or in this case the K type. Is there a way to do that as well?

Comment: Probably not. I have tried some things but nothing worked.  I think that how comments are treated by the IDE is not even standardized, at least I could not find a resource on it. So what works, say, in VSCode, does not necessarily work elsewhere.

Comment: Ye, me too, either way thanks for trying :)